# Relationship between complexity classes W[1]-hard and NP-hard?

Tags: reductions, np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions

If i have a parameterized reduction from multicolored independent set (W[$1$]-hard) to some problem $A$, which take polynomial time. Can i say that problem $A$ is NP-hard?

in other words, Is multicolored independent set (non-parameter version) NP-hard?

Further, does exists a problem belongs to W[1]-hard but don't belong to NP-hard?

Comment: Yes, because multicoloured independent set is NP-hard.